# Jquery Button padding right

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and I am using query's buttons. I am trying to get the right side of the button to become flush with the images above it.

I have tried to push the margin one px at a time and at 11px the right hand button gets pushed down to the next line...but at 10px the button remains on the same line but not flush with the images above it.

When I put on border: 1px solid red; it shows that there is a few pixels extra on the right hand side of the button.

I want to know if there is a way to remove that extra space on the right hand side.

If the few extra are removed then I'll be able to get the button and images flushed.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="gal1Buttons">
    <a href="#userList" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Different User</a>
  </div>

  <div class="gal1Buttons2">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="b">Connect User</a>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .gal1Buttons{
   float: left; 
 }

 .gal1Buttons2{
   float: left; 
   padding-right: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   border: 1px solid red ;
 }
```

Comment: You must have other styles adding the spacing... the code you provided has no space... http://jsfiddle.net/e65r4srr/

Comment: I have added no additional code....the only thing I can think of is the jquery mobile has some code somewhere that adds the space

Comment: I used the inspect element tool and found that jquery mobile was adding a margin of like .625em...so i had to override that

Comment: You can try: .gal1Buttons2 .ui-mini{margin-right:0px !important;}